# What's the best query to get last commented articles?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table `comment` like :

```
id  article_id    approved  created_at
7   104506        1         2019-12-02 09:36:32
6   104452        0         2019-12-02 09:31:35   
5   104498        1         2019-12-02 09:27:56
4   104506        1         2019-12-02 09:05:45
3   104511        1         2019-12-02 08:58:56
2   104501        1         2019-12-02 08:52:57
1   104552        1         2019-12-02 08:50:10
```

What I would like:

```
104506
104498
104511
104501
104552
```

and I would like to get a distinct list of article_id approved order by created_at desc

So I just do this:
`SELECT article_id FROM comment WHERE approved = 1 GROUP BY article_id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 30`

But on a 400k rows table, it takes 1,28 secs.

Any idea to have a faster query? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the search terms you used in Google when you were researching this issue?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b877db/1

Comment: I believe this is the common [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem. There are many similar questions on Stack Overflow with good answers. Follow that tag to find them.

Comment: Thanks for the good tag!

Comment: You have a contradiction -- 104506 was created at two different times.  Which time should be used??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to write the query like this:

```
SELECT article_id
FROM comment
WHERE approved = 1
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

For this, you want an index on `comment(approved, article_id, created_at)`.

Comment: You're right, I had 3 distinct index on approved, article_id and created_at. And creating 1 index with this 3 fields reduce query time from 1,28 secs to 100 ms. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to check how the existing indexes behave you can run an [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) query :

```sql
EXPLAIN
SELECT article_id
FROM comment
WHERE approved = 1
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

It will tell which indexes are used, how they are used, and also which WHERE conditions, ORDER sorts, JOIN conditions (and maybe others) are in need of indexing. So you can try adding a new one that will fill all of them.

- a warning though : each new index will slow down the writing, so better to aim straight.
- but one index can be used for various queries : in a 3 fields indexes for instance, it will be used for queries that need indexing on fields (1), (1, 2) or (1, 2, 3) but not (2), (3), (1, 3) or (2, 3).

For a broader inspection of an app or a website about indexes, there is a [log_queries_not_using_indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_queries_not_using_indexes) configuration flag that can be enabled (not to be used in production).